# Magento 1 : Is it possible restrict admin user view only selected store details by using observer or anything?

Tags: permissions, magento1.9.2.3, admin-user, restriction

How can i restrict admin user view only selected store details by using observer or anything?

[image]

Comment: try to do with store role access...

Comment: What event i need to use?

Comment: can you please explain in brief.....

Comment: Consider you are one of my admin user, you need to view only store 3 orders only https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjk6U.png